# Largest Rectangle in Histogram: Why is the big O of this code O(nlog(n))?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

In LeetCode problem #84, ["Largest Rectangle in Histogram"](https://leetcode.com/problems/largest-rectangle-in-histogram/), we're given a bar graph in the form  `int[] heights`, and we need to find and return the area of the "largest rectangle" in the bar graph, meaning the maximum possible value of `(j - i + 1) * min(heights[i], heights[i+1], ..., heights[j-1], heights[j])` (by choosing `i` and `j` appropriately).

Apparently the below solution gives average-case time complexity in O(*n* log *n*), worst-case time complexity in O(*n*<sup>2</sup>), and space complexity in O(*n*). Why is that? I'm particularly perplexed about how to think about it so that O(*n* log *n*) makes sense.

```
public class Solution {
    public int calculateArea(int[] heights, int start, int end) {
        if (start > end)
            return 0;
        int minindex = start;
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            if (heights[minindex] > heights[i]) {
                minindex = i;
            }
        }
        return Math.max(
            heights[minindex] * (end - start + 1),
            Math.max(
                calculateArea(heights, start, minindex - 1),
                calculateArea(heights, minindex + 1, end)));
    }

    public int largestRectangleArea(int[] heights) {
        return calculateArea(heights, 0, heights.length - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: The space complexity is O(n) because you have to factor in the stack space in recursive calls. "When you make a recursive call the cpu needs to remember where to continue execution of your program so the state is saved and a copy of your function push on the stack"

Comment: Regarding the time complexity: the algorithm seems to follow a "divide and conquer" strategy, so I imagine the average-case analysis would be similar to [the one for Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Average-case_analysis).  Perhaps someone else can provide a formal proof, I'm not that skilled I'm afraid.

Comment: "why the average case time complexity is O(nlog(n)), the worst case O(n2) and the space requirement being O(n)?" Well, what do you think the values *should* be? What is your reasoning?